# Dropper/Hopper system not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have it set up so that when a button is pushed, this line of redstone should activate, meaning that the hoppers should pick it up and funnel it away. But for some reason, the middle dropper never drops an item and I am confused on why. Any idea? [image: Picutre from inside]

Comment: Might be irrelevant but, did you check the hopper's orientation?

Comment: the hoppers should pick what up? hoppers are deactivated when powered by redstone.